# When filtering resources in Gradle, how can I defer the evaluation of a token until the execution phase?

Tags: gradle

I have the following configuration for processing resources:

```groovy
project.ext.releaseVersion = {
    project.version.contains("SNAPSHOT") ? timestamp : project.version
}

processResources {
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: project.ext.releaseVersion()])
}
```

It works, but `project.ext.releaseVersion()` gets evaluated in the configuration phase and I can't figure out how to delay it until the execution phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is as simple as applying the filter in a `doFirst` block (as Peter commented above).  I also got rid of the closure for getting an updated value, but that may just be personal preference.

```groovy
processResources {
    doFirst {
        def releaseVersion =
            project.version.contains("SNAPSHOT") ? project.ext.timestamp : project.version

        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: releaseVersion])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap configuring `processResources` in [`afterEvaluate()`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3aafterEvaluate%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method call to delay the evaluation:

```
afterEvaluate {
    processResources {
        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: project.ext.releaseVersion()])
    }
}
```

Comment: This delays it until the project has been evaluated. To delay until the execution phase, one would use `processResources.doFirst { ... }`.